# How to get minimal vendor information about the TPM chip installed in my laptop

Tags: linux, security, encryption, secure-boot, tpm

How do I get some minimal information about the TPM chip in my Linux laptop?

Information such as the manufacturer, manufacturer id, manufacturer version.

So far I have tried the `tpm2_getcap` command to get some vendor information.

`tpm2_getcap vendor` and `tpm2_getcap vendor:2`. both times I get the following error,

```
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_GetCapability.c:301:Esys_GetCapability_Finish() Received TPM Error 
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_GetCapability.c:106:Esys_GetCapability() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000001c4) 
ERROR: Esys_GetCapability(0x1C4) - tpm:parameter(1):value is out of range or is not correct for the context
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_getcap
```

**Side Note**: Commands such as `tpm2_getcap algorithms` and `tpm2_getcap pcrs` works fine.

> Are you 100% you have a discrete TPM?

Yes.

Comment: Are you 100% you have a discrete TPM?

Comment: Perhaps you have a tpm1 rather than a tpm2 chip. You need to hunt out the specs for the laptop. If you do have a tpm1 running chip,. then you /may/ be able to update its firmware for tpm2. That code can be found somewhere on the supermicro web site.